# Ruby on Rails URL: use other models data within to_param method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, web-applications, rails-activerecord

I'm new to rails. I want to create simple url for the users, I don't want to use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), if possible. I can already change the url using this

```
#MyModel.rb
def to_param
  address
end

#MyController.rb
  @user = Admin::Account.find_by_address(params[:id])
```

but what I really want is to use name instead of address, but the problem is that, name does not belong to MyModel.rb it balongs to OtherModel.rb, is this even pissible? please help

here is a sample of what I want

> ```
>  #MyModel.rb
>     def to_param
>       name #name is a data/column from OtherModel.rb
>     end
>
>     #MyController.rb
>       @user = Admin::Account.find_by_name(params[:id]) 
>     #instead of using find_by_address I can now use find_by_name
> ```

here is a sample of my model relations

```
class Admin::MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :other_model, :class_name => 'Admin::OtherModel',  dependent: :destroy
end

class Admin::OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :my_model, :class_name => 'Admin::MyModel'
end
```

Comment: Why don't you post your actual model relations?

Comment: okay I will modify my question

Comment: hi @SergioTulentsev I had already modified my question together with my sample model relations

Comment: And what do you want to query by an attribute of what model?

Comment: I want to query the name attribute of OtherModel.rb. And the query should be inside method to_param in MyModel.rb, I had modified again my question together with an example code of what I want to happen :)